# I upgraded my app from struts 2.0X to 2.1X for using jquery grid plugin But getting error

Tags: struts2

I upgraded my app  from struts 2.0X to 2.1X for using jquery grid plugin But getting a following error .

> Caused by: Unable to load bean:
>   type:com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory
>   class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory - bean -
>   jar:file:/F:/Jportalsvn/trunk/Jportal/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:71:140

Comment: Have you updated xwork-core-2.2.3.jar file?

Comment: List the jars on your classpath and perhaps your pom if using maven.

Answer (score 1):

In first short it seems that the error is most likely is being caused by sets of jars competing causing an environment issue.Make sure you have no jar conflict as indicated for `struts2-core-2.2.3.jar`.

Try doing a complete clean and redeploy and make sure that the old libraries are not
being deployed or are still there.

Hope this should resolve your problem and if it still persist i suggest you to go for a small steps like creating a small hello-world application to check if everything is fine and workin properly.

Comment: I have already done both , first didnt work out and second one work fine but when i create my complete webapp with it , It gives the same erro :(......

Comment: @AbheyGupta: Can you post complete error stack? and can you specify what all S2 jars you have in your class-path?

Comment: i was using Google open id API with in project , it was responsible for conflicts between some jar , Now i have rectified it . Thanks for your concern .

Answer (score 0):

***This problem is due to incompatible jars.*** Make sure that you replace a appropriate xwork2.1.x.jar in lib folder. (When you copy a Struts2.0x.jar then it needs the corresponding xwork2.jar). Make sure that

1. ognl.jar
2. commons-logging.jar
3. struts.jar
4. xwork.jar
   are compatible to each other. This problem can be avoided.